# A Combinatorics Problem: Where Did I Go Wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am trying to solve a combinatorics problem, specifically problem 2iii). I have an answer, but the textbook says it's wrong:

[image]

What I did was 12! - 11! - 10! - 9! - 8!, because 12! is the total number of combination, and 11! is the number of combinations if we have 2 girls together, etc.

I would appreciate it if you would do 2 things:

1. Can you explain to me where I went wrong?
2. Also, can you explain to me why the textbook's answer is $7!\binom855!$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To exclude those arrangements in which two or more girls are together, you would have to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit after OP's edit:

Your textbook is right concerning (iii).

Let's analyze the situation:

- For the $7$ boys you get: $\Rightarrow \color{blue}{7!}$
- When you line the boys up, they provide $8$ "slots" where to put exactly one girl. So, choose $5$ of these $8$ slots: $\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\binom 8 5}$
- The $5$ girls themselves can also be arranged: $\Rightarrow \color{blue}{5!}$

All together
$$\color{blue}{7! \cdot \binom 8 5 \cdot 5!}$$

Note that I cannot explain where you made a mistake as you need to give more details about your reasoning.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I meant 12iii) instead of 12iv).

Comment: Wait a minute. This has a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for changing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fix AGGGB as one then this plus seven remaining can be seated in 8! ways.  The three girls between A and B can be chosen in ${5\choose3}$ ways and the three girls can be permuted in 3! ways to a total of $8!{5\choose3}3!$.   The two boys A and B can be permuted in 2! ways to a total of $8!{5\choose3}3!2!$

Comment: The OP changed the question. So, your answer isn't valid anymore. Just to let you know.